# Joining two tables on a column value with sorting according to other columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I am trying to join these two tables

**Table 1**

```
Subject_id  time_x   x_value
----------  ------   -------
  123       12:00     4
  123       15:00     3
  123       19:00     2
  123       21:00     1
```

**Table 2**

```
Subject_id time_y   y_value
---------- -------  --------
    123    13:00       22
    123    14:00       25
    123    15:00       24
    123    16:00       36
    123    17:00       22
    123    18:00       25
    123    19:00       26
    123    20:00       45
```

on column `subject_id` and the result has to be like below

**Result**

```
Subject_id  x_value y_value time_x  time_y  
----------  ------- ------- ------  ------   
  123        4      null    12:00    12:00
  123       null     22     13:00    13:00  
  123       null     25     14:00    14:00  
  123        3       24     15:00    15:00  
  123       null     36     16:00    16:00  
  123       null     22     17:00    17:00  
  123       null     25     18:00    18:00  
  123        2       26     19:00    19:00  
  123       null     45     20:00    20:00  
  123        1      null    21:00    21:00
```

So can you please help me to achieve these results.

Comment: Try full join!!

Comment: I tried it but the issue is with time misalignment between the x values and y values and also x values get duplicated to fill the frequency difference. can you please help me overcome this issue? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select union for obtain all the time and then left join with each table

```
  select t.subject_id, t1.x_value, t2.y_value, t.my_time time_x, t.my_time time_y
  from  (
    select  subject_id, time_x my_time 
    from table1 
    union  
    select subject_id, time_y  
    from table2 
  ) t 
  left join  table1 t1 on t.subject_id = t1.subject_id
    and t.my_time  = t1.time_x
  left join  table2 t2 on t.subject_id = t2.subject_id
    and t.my_time  = t2.time_y
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have two time columns.  So, I think you want:

```
select coalesce(t1.subject_id, t2.subject_id) as subject_id,
       t1.x_value, t2.y_value,
       coalesce(t1.time_x, t2.time_y) as time
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t2.subject_id = t1.subject_id and t2.time_y = t1.time_x;
```

You can duplicate the `time` column if you like, but I don't think that is necessary.